# ECS Fargate foverver with "rolloutState" in "IN_PROGRESS" with no stopped task on AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using ECS with Fargate, I have a service running and it is working OK.But after I update the task definition (new deploy) and the console (ECS -> Clusters -> Tasks tab) shows that my current task is INACTIVE, which is normal, but it doesn't show any new task being created, nor any stopped task, even after an hour. It is as if ECS is not trying to run my new definition.

If I use the awscli to find information about my service:

```
aws ecs describe-services --cluster cluster-xxxxxxx  --services service-svc-xxxxxxx  --region us-east-1
```

It has two deployments. The first is alright, it is the running deployment. The most recent one, it shows:

```
          "desiredCount": 1,
          "pendingCount": 0,
          "runningCount": 0,
          "failedTasks": 7,
          ...
          "rolloutState": "IN_PROGRESS",
          "rolloutStateReason": "ECS deployment ecs-svc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX in progress."
```

Again, there is nothing on the ECS console that points to failed tasks. It is as if the task is failing on a so premature state, its not even logging anything.

I tried looking at CloudTrail event, but there is nothing there about failed tasks. On CloudWatch, the logs for container insights (/aws/ecs/containerinsights/cluster-xxxxxxx/performance) also don't mention failing tasks.

How can I troubleshoot this situation?

Comment: In the UI there is a toggle to switch to `stopped` tasks. Is it possible that you are not in that view? The `stopped` view should show all tasks that have been stopped or that have failed to start.

Comment: On the "Task" tab, when I point "Desired task status:" to "Stopped" it shows an empty list with "No Results".

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that stopped tasks from that list get purged after a few hours (i.e. they disappears). Just to make sure you are running in the right place I'd just run a task quick, stop it and check the `Stopped` list if you see it.

Comment: @mreferre, I thought that too. Then I kept monitoring the list shortly after attempting a new deploy. Nothing showed up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if the account/organization is new, then AWS apply quotas that seems not to be documented anywhere. ECS was not authorized to start more than two tasks.

There is a trick, I found on this post, that says that I had to create an EC2 instance on the same region I was trying to use ECS. Shortly after I created the EC2 instance, I received an email from AWS and everything behaved normally again. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=340770